# Iterate Model List in Flex AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, iterator, flex3

how to iterate model list in flex as3 
My code:

```
var list:ArrayList=new ArrayList();
var per:Person=new Person();                
per.person_id=1;                
per.fname="james";
per.userid="12";
list.addItem(per);  

 for each (var p:Person in list)
   {
    trace("name----------"+p.fname);
   }
```

but the above iterator not working...
how can iterate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `for each` you can try normal `for` loop

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
 var p:Person = Person (list.getitemAt(i));
 trace(p.fname);
}
```

this will work fine...